# TypeError byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, string

Question in regards to a TypeError which I am receiving for my code.

The Beginning of the Code:

```
domain = "https://bdgastore.com"
handle = 'xt-4-advanced-8'
url = domain + "/products/" + handle + ".json"

##
# Product information
##
shoeSize = "11"
quantity = "1"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--headless") # Comment that line to see script running in Chrome.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()

#information
first_name='Name';
family_name='Last Name';
email='youremail@gmail.com';
address='12345 Some Street';
country='AU';
city='Mermaid Beach';
postcode='4218';
state='QLD';
mobile='0421667754';
CCNumber="1"
CCName="Test"
CCExpiry="11/25"
CCVerification="123"

#Checkout process
checkoutDetails = 'checkout[shipping_address][first_name]='+ first_name +'&checkout[shipping_address][last_name]='+ family_name +'&checkout[email]='+ email +'&checkout[shipping_address][address1]='+ address +'&checkout[shipping_address][city]='+ city +'&checkout[shipping_address][zip]='+ postcode +'&checkout[shipping_address][country_code]='+ country +'&&checkout[shipping_address][province_code]='+ state +'&checkout[shipping_address][phone]='+ mobile;
```

The code is the following:

```
for variants in data['product']['variants']: 
if ((variants['inventory_quantity'] > 0) and (variants['title'] == shoeSize)):
    link = domain + '/cart/'+ str(variants['id']) +':'+ quantity +'?'+ checkoutDetails;
    driver.get(link)
```

While else the error which I am receiving is

```
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thank you so much in advance and sorry, I'm still new to this.

Comment: don't index a `bytes` object with a `str`.

Comment: Can you provide data for `data` or `variants`, just a little bit.

Comment: `data` is most likely of type `byte`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [`example`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) given in the document, you can see that read returns data of type byte.

As you can see from the code you provided, you are probably expecting it to be of type dict, then you can parse it through the `json.loads` method.

```py
import json

print(json.loads(b'{"a": 1}'))
# {'a': 1}
```

Modify the code

```py
import json
...

for variants in json.loads(data)['product']['variants']: 
if ((variants['inventory_quantity'] > 0) and (variants['title'] == shoeSize)):
    link = domain + '/cart/'+ str(variants['id']) +':'+ quantity +'?'+ checkoutDetails;
    driver.get(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variants['title'] # <-- this should be an index
```

Something like:

```
variants[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the response before using it. Try:

```
data = response.read().decode(response.headers.get_content_charset())
```